# how can i call my function just once to translate,rotate etc?

Tags: matlab, affinetransform

hello i have a function and a problem :)

```
function[result] = transform_vertices(v, m)
    for i = 1 : size(v,2)
        v(:,i) = m * v(:,i); 
    end
    result = v;
end
```

i should use this function(transform_vertices) just ONCE to rotate ,translate but how can i use just once? my code is

```
image1_vertices = quad;
image1_vertices = transform_vertices(transform_vertices(quad,mrotate(30)),mtranslate(-2,0));

> PS: mtranslate and mrotate are also function which calculates
> rotation,translation
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Why can't you just use a single call to the function? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @mikkola what i achieve is actually , just simple rotation(30degree) and translation (-2,0)    but just one call for function doesnt work or i cant figure i dont know

Comment: If you define an appropriate [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) you can apply a rotation and translation to a vector by a single matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `quad` is a set of coordinates? Your `transform_vertices` function does nothing more than a left matrix multiplication. So you would get the same result if you do:

```
image1_vertices = transform_vertices(quad, mtranslate(-2,0)*mrotate(30));
```

In fact, you don't even need to use the function, you can just do:

```
image1_vertices = mtranslate(-2,0) * mrotate(30) * quad;
```

Comment: thx ! yes quad is exactly how you think of and this form worked perfectly